# How to read varbinary datatype values in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am creating a chat application in node js with MySQL
I have saved emojis and message text as varbinary datatype of MySQL. and it all the chat messages saved successfully with emojis

but when I tried reading the data it not read the varbinary values I have also use filereader module to read the data
filereader.readAsText(element.text);

but not getting success.

If anyone has the solution or anyone has the solution to save emojis and text as varchar then please guide me regarding that topic.

Answer (score 0):

simple toString() function is used to convert binary values to text.